# Android, HttpListener

Tags: android, httplistener

I'm fairly new to Android so my question is how do we create an HttpListener on Android device? My task is to create a listener on one android device and request a contact number from second android device & send the data back n forth. Can any one help me?

E.g:
**Android Device 1 (Containing Listener)**

**Android Device 2 (Client)**
Requesting Url to Android Device 1: http://192.122.1.2:8888/GetContactDetail?id=2
Response Received: "111111111111"

Any suggestion on how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, thanks to @elevine suggestion, I was able to do it successfully but as suggested by @Peter Knego the limitations are still there. This will work on LAN without any problem.

Hope this helps someone.

http://codersapprentice.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-integrate-jetty-server-in-my.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using i-Jetty to run an a webserver on your first device: http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

If you have never created a web application before, you can do the development on a laptop and get your second device working with it.  Then deploy the application onto i-jetty when its ready.

Comment: I looked at it but wasn't able to find any example that can help me understand.

Comment: Your first device needs to run a webserver, which is what i-jetty will give you.  First, you'll have to build a java web application and load it into i-jetty.  If you don't know how to do that, you should grab a book on Java servlets.

Comment: BTW, what you want is an HTTP server, not a listener.  Using the right terminology should help you search for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In practice this won't work since most networks (mobile and wifi) use [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). NAT prevents inbound connections to device, which basically means that you can not run servers on mobile devices.

Your approach would only work if both devices are on same local network.

**Update**

You need to embedd a http server into your app: http://tjws.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you tell me, "can i get the url to which the data is posted & posted data itself" in socket communication

Comment: I know how to get the "Posted/Sent Data"